# Running Opencv from the remote machine

Tags: python, linux, windows, opencv, ssh

I have login into the Linux machine from my windows machine using `ssh -X username@host`.
I am trying to run my OpenCV python program but it is showing error -

> Unable to init server: Could not connect:  Connection refused(Frame:21109): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:38:23.942: cannot open display:

I tried setting `export DISPLAY=:0` but it seems to not work

Comment: Remove the `cv2.imshow()`, `cv2.waitkey()` or `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` from the source code.

Comment: You need to run an X11 Server on your Windows box or preferably install Linux on it.

Comment: @ZdaR but while one needs those 3 options then how to solve them?